# What is the picture of the basis elements under the metric $d'(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + \cdots + |x_n - y_n|$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Background:** In section 20 "The Metric Topology" of Munkres's Topology, several common metrics are considered on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. For instance, the *euclidean metric* $d$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is defined by the equation $d(x,y) = [(x_1 - y_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_n - y_n)^2]^{1/2}$; the *square metric* $\rho$ is defined by the equation $\rho(x,y) = \max \{ |x_1 - y_1|, \cdots,  |x_n - y_n| \}$.

Also, the author remarks that

> In the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, the basis elements under $d$ can be pictured as circular regions, while the basis elements under $\rho$ can be pictured as square regions.

**About the Problem:** In exercise 1, another metric $d'$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is introduced and defined by the equation $d'(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + \cdots + |x_n - y_n|$. I am able to solve the problem itself. However, I failed to illustrate the basis elements under $d'$.

Therefore, my problem is

> What is the picture of the basis elements under the metric $d'(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + \cdots + |x_n - y_n|$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: In dimension 2: start with the first quadrant and use  symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squares rotated 90 degrees (i.e., diamond shapes).

Comment: It makes sense to me *by picture*. However, are there some more *formal* arguments?

Comment: Look at the basis elements around the origin, $Q$, so the set of points $P$ where $d(Q, P) < r$. I'll do this for $r = 1$, the others are similar. We'll look at the case where $P = (x, y)$ and $x, y \ge 0$; the other three are similar. Then $d(Q, P) = |x-0| + |y-0| = |x|+ |y| = x+y$; setting $x + y < 1$ gives a triangle (with missing hypotenuse) with vertices $(0,0), (1, 0), and (0, 1)$ in the first quadrant. Corresponding arguments for the other three quadrants give you a square. For instance, in the $x>0, y<0$ quadrant, we get $|x|+|y| = x-y$; $x-y \le 1$ gives verts $(0,0), (1,0), (0,-1)$.

Comment: By "give you a square" in the previous comment, I mean "Give you the other three triangles that, together with the first, constitute a rotated square." Sorry to have been unclear.